# Take a value inside a array list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

everyone i have one problem to solve in my application i need take an specific value inside my array  an put him into my table to show this values for users.
See my code below:

my mock data

```
{
      "Data": "2020-09-21",
      "Horario":"09:00:00",
      "Segunda": [
        {
          "Periodo": "1",
          "HorarioInicio": "9:00:00",
          "HorarioTermino": "10:50:00",
          "IdDisciplina": "396",
          "DescricaoDisciplina": "Arte (Artes Visuais)",
          "DescricaoReduzidaDisciplina": "Arte Vi.",
          "DescricaoTurno": "Manhã",
          "IdEstabelecimento": "43",
          "DescricaoEstabelecimento": "Colégio Correio Lima",
          "TipoSituacaoHorario": "Normal"
        },
}
```

i need acess an values inside my array Segunda

my interface

```
interface ISegunda {
  Periodo: string;
  HorarioInicio: string;
  HorarioTermino: string;
  IdDisciplina: string;
  DescricaoDisciplina: string;
  DescricaoReduzidaDisciplina: string;
  DescricaoTurno: string;
  IdEstabelecimento: string;
  DescricaoEstabelecimento: string;
  TipoSituacaoHorario: string;
}

export interface IAgendaAulas {
  Data: string;
  Horario: string;
  Segunda: ISegunda[];
}
```

my service

```
const getAgendaAulas = async (
  dataAula: string
): Promise<IAgendaAulas[] | undefined> => {
  try {
    const { data } = await Api().get<IAgendaAulas[]>(
      `/agenda-aulas?DataAula=${dataAula}`
    );
    if (data) {
      return data;
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return undefined;
  }
};
```

her is my tsx view

```
interface IAgendasAulasProps {
  agendaDeAulas: IAgendaAulas[];
  dataAtualizada: string;
}

export const TabelaHorariosAulas: React.FC<IAgendasAulasProps> = ({
  agendaDeAulas,
  dataAtualizada,
}) => {
  const [aulas, setAulas] = useState<IAgendaAulas[]>();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    AgendaTurmaService.getAgendaAulas(dataAtualizada).then((data) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (data) {
        setAulas(data);
      } else {
        setAulas([])
      }
    });
  }, [dataAtualizada]);

return (
<Grid container>
        <Grid item sm={12}>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table stickyHeader>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>Horário</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Segunda</TableCell>                  
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>

              <TableBody>
                {aulas?.map((horario, indexAulas) => (
                  <>
                    <TableRow>
                      <TableCell>{}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{}</TableCell>                      
                    </TableRow>
                  </>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
             </Table>
            </TableContainer>
           </Grid>
          </Grid>
```

i hope someone can help me with my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use array destructuring like this:

```
  const { Segunda } = aulas;

  Segunda.map((i) => i.HorarioInicio, i.HorarioInicio......;
```

Also you can rename it Segunda:

```
  const { Segunda: items } = aulas;

  items.map((i) => i.HorarioInicio, i.HorarioInicio......;
```

Editing your own code it will be like this:

It should work

```
interface IAgendasAulasProps {
  agendaDeAulas: IAgendaAulas[];
  dataAtualizada: string;
}

export const TabelaHorariosAulas: React.FC<IAgendasAulasProps> = ({
  agendaDeAulas,
  dataAtualizada,
}) => {
  const [aulas, setAulas] = useState<IAgendaAulas[]>();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    AgendaTurmaService.getAgendaAulas(dataAtualizada).then((data) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (data) {
        setAulas(data);
      } else {
        setAulas([])
      }
    });
  }, [dataAtualizada]);


const { Segunda: items } = aulas;

return (
<Grid container>
        <Grid item sm={12}>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table stickyHeader>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>Horário</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Segunda</TableCell>                  
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>

              <TableBody>
                {items.map(({horario, indexAulas}) => (
                  <>
                    <TableRow>
                      <TableCell>{horario}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{indexAulas}</TableCell>                      
                    </TableRow>
                  </>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
             </Table>
            </TableContainer>
           </Grid>
          </Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand your answear

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can destructure with object, array destructuring
const { Segunda: items } = aulas;
So you can then access to Segunda array. Then you can destructure again to access the item you want to output with {} eg: .map(({a,b,c}) => a,b,c) or just use a name eg: .map(i => i.a, i.b, i.c)